# I wonder if inclusivity would be better than inclusion in this scenario?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

[It is said that](https://www.businessinsider.com/amazon-ceo-andy-jassys-comments-diversity-put-to-the-test-2021-2) Amazon would add "inclusion" to their leadership principles:

> Just weeks later after Bezos's memo, Amazon employees shared stories of racial and gender discrimination they experienced at work as part of an effort to add "inclusion" to the company's leadership principles

In another article: [Moore's Law for Everything](https://moores.samaltman.com/) by Sam Altman, the same meaning was expressed using "inclusivity":

> A stable economic system requires two components: growth and inclusivity.

I wonder if "[inclusivity](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=inclusivity+definition&oq=inclusivity+defin&aqs=chrome.0.0i433j69i57j0l3j0i22i30l2j69i60.3127j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" would be a better fit than "[inclusion](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=inclusion+define&oq=inclusion+define&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433j0l8.3218j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" for the Amazon case? In my opinion, "inclusivity" is implying more specifically equal opportunities and inclusiveness without discrimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Inclusivity**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inclusivity) is defined as:

> the fact or **policy of not excluding** members or participants on the
> grounds of gender, race, class, sexuality, disability, etc.

**[Inclusion](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inclusion)** is defined as:

> the practice or **policy of including** and integrating all people and
> groups in activities, organizations, political processes, etc.,
> especially those who are disadvantaged, have suffered discrimination,
> or are living with disabilities

There is a vast difference between a "policy of *not excluding*" and "a policy of *including*," a difference akin to the difference between a policy of *tolerance* and a policy of *acceptance*, a difference allegorically not unlike the difference between *not losing* and *winning*, a difference Sun Tzu expounds on in *The Art of War*, a difference that often makes all the difference, so by using "inclusion" rather than "inclusivity," Amazon, at least semantically, is expressing that it would add *including* rather than *not excluding* to its leadership principles.

Furthermore, the buzzword in the zeitgeist for this is "inclusion," not "inclusivity," likely because of the very difference cited above, and Amazon, being quite keenly attuned to buzz, to the zeitgeist, positioning itself on the cutting edge of it all even, even a buzz creator, is of course going to use "inclusion," not "inclusivity."